# Maximum number of groups in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I had assumed the maximum was 9 but after some experimentation I know it is not.  The javadocs  for [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to not list a maximum.

Comment: Why did you assume the maximum was 9?

Comment: There are regex flavors that limit you to nine groups; Jakarta Regexp is one of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no explicit ceiling, so theoretically the max would be Integer.MAX_VALUE. Practically speaking, the max will vary according the resources available, but I'm sure it's a lot more than you'll ever need.